# Tips with AsyncTask cleanup and usage Android

Tags: android, performance, webview, android-asynctask

This is the first time I used AsyncTask and it works but it's very dirty as I just copied and pasted some code. I want to do it the right way and as clean as possible. So can anyone help me with cleaning up my code and tell me how to do it the right way? You would do me a great favor in helping me and giving me more experience in future Android developing. I want to learn it the right way from the start ;)

**EDIT:** 
After reading a bunch of tutorials and watching video's I think I made an huge improvement! And I'm very happy I did it! But there's only one small problem left. At the startup of the app, it doesn't load the page. The shouldOverrideUrlLoading works great after I clicked a link but at the startup it shows only a blank screen. What's the problem?

```
public class WebviewActivity extends MainActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean mConnection = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                new checkConnection().execute();
                if (mConnection == true){
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }           
                return true;                
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mainScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            }
        });

        myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       
        new checkConnection().execute();
        if (mConnection == true){
            myWebView.loadUrl(webLink);
        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //-----DOING THE CONNECTION CHECK IN ANOTHER THREAD-----
    //------------------------------------------------------

    public class checkConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        int mStatusCode = 0;
        Exception mConnectionException;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();           
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebviewActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    URL url = new URL(webLink);
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5); // mTimeout is in seconds
                    urlc.connect();

                    mStatusCode = urlc.getResponseCode();

                    if (mStatusCode == 200){
                        //Nothing to do.
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mConnectionException = e;
            }
            return null;
        }   

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param){
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (mStatusCode  == 200){
                mConnection = true;
            }
            else if (mStatusCode  == 404){
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage404.html");
            }
            else {
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't call `progressDialog.dismiss();` from `doInBackground()`, use `onPostExecute()` instead. `doInBackground()` is not an UI thread, so trying to manipulate UI elements might give you wild consequences.

Here's why you don't get your page loaded on the first try:

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            new checkConnection().execute();  <- (1)
            if (mConnection == true){         <- (2)
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }           
            return true;
```

(1) starts asynchronous task, which is going to be finished some time in the future
(2) tries to check the results of (1) **immediately**, so there are no results yet.

---

here's modified version of your `AsyncTask`, which accepts url as a parameter:

```
public class checkConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{     <------ change this

    int mStatusCode = 0;
    Exception mConnectionException;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();           
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebviewActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {     <------ change this
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                URL url = new URL(webLink);
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5); // mTimeout is in seconds
                urlc.connect();

                mStatusCode = urlc.getResponseCode();

                if (mStatusCode == 200){
                    //Nothing to do.
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mConnectionException = e;
        }
        return params[0];     <------ change this
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String param){     <------ change this
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (mStatusCode  == 200){
            myWebView.loadUrl(param);     <------ change this
        }
        else if (mStatusCode  == 404){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage404.html");
        }
        else {
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I've made an huge improvement right now. Check my main post. The only problem that I have right now is that it doesn't load the page at the first startup. Can you see why?

Comment: Ah okay, that's clear. But how can I check if (1) is finished?

Comment: you don't have to check. move `view.loadUrl()` into the `AsyncTask`, so it's loaded as soon as you've checked your website is available. and, btw, it's faster to check if you use `setRequestMethod()` to specify `HEAD` method instead of default `GET`, which retrieves the whole page.

Comment: and your version of `onResume()` has the same problem as described above, please, don't forget to fix that too.

Comment: Okay I will fix that, thank you! The thing is why I did it this way with the view.loadUrl() outside of the asynctask. Is because the loadUrl from the onResume() is different from the loadUrl() from the shouldOverrideUrlLoading(). So I cannot simply move that to the asynctask. Or should I give the execute some input that gets recognised by the asynctask so it can choose the right one with if and elseif?

Comment: inside your `onPostExecute()` you may put `myWebView.loadUrl(webLink);` instead of `mConnection = true;` and it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes it works fine at startup ;) But then the shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesn't work anymore like it should. If I click a link, it's only going to the main link instead of the clicked page. And that's because in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading part it should have view.loadUrl(url); instead of the other :)

Comment: just pass an url as a parameter to the `new checkConnection().execute();`, this should fix the problem, i guess?

Comment: i've added new version of `AsyncTask` to the answer with changed places marked as "< -- change this"

Comment: Thank you sir! It works like a charm. You just learned me a whole bunch of new stuff that I finally understand. Thank you and have a nice day! ;)

Comment: Have fun developing for Android! =)